# Why I can't see the details of an object(ID, name,etc). I am using mvc 4, razor, entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my BussinessLayer I have ActivityService.cs with the next function:

```
public Activity GetActivityByID(string activityID)
    {
        return _context.REE_ACTIVITY.Find(activityID);
    }
```

In my Controller I have:

```
 public ActionResult ShowActivity(string id)
    {
        Activity activity = _activityService.GetActivityByID(id);
        return View(activity);
    }
```

In the view with the Activity list I have.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var act in Model)
      {
       <tr>
           <td id = "tdIdActivity">@Html.ActionLink(@act.IdActivity, "ShowActivity", "Activityes")</td>
           <td style= "text-align:left">@act.NameActivity @act.Equipement.NameEquipement - @act.TypesEquipement.NameTypeObjet</td>
           <td  id = "activityDate">@act.ActivityDate</td>
       </tr>
      }
</tbody>
```

And in my DetailsView I am first showing the ID then anothers properties:

```
<div class = "Container">
     <div >Activité numéro: @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdActivity)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem ? did you get any error ?

Comment: No, instead of its Id like "2014-00001" I just see Activité numéro: IdActivity.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdActivity)
```

This create a Label with the **name of the field, not it's value**.

That's your problem; because I figure you want the actual value.

```
@Model.IdActivity
```

*assuming you pass a single instance to your view.*

Comment: I tried but I had a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Then your `Model` is null. Hence why I wrote `assuming you pass a single instance to your view`. Without knowing how the controller method is set up, I can't help you.

Comment: +1 for actually solving the problem with displaying the variable. I agree with Flater, we cannot help you without knowing what is happening on this line `Activity activity = _activityService.GetActivityByID(id);` You should trace it and see why it's returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller appears to be returning a single `Activity` instance as the model:

```
Activity activity = _activityService.GetActivityByID(id);
return View(activity);
```

But your View seems to be expecting a Model that is a collection of activities:

```
@foreach (var act in Model)
```

Comment: To show the activity list I have another controller:public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var activity = from act in _serviceActivite.GetActivites()
                            select act;
            return View(activity);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning your problem in question.
Be more descriptive and explain what you are expecting and what do you get.

In your index view try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "ShowActivity", "Activityes", new {id=Model.IdActivity})
```

Here, "**Details**", is the text you want to give to actionlink, "**ShowActivity**" is the controller's method, "**Activities**" is the name controller and through new you are passing value of IdActivity to controllers parameter.

Comment: I have in the Index View a list with activities and I need, when I click on one item, to see its details including the Id.

Comment: Actually I don't need to give a name to the actionlink because ActivityId is the value of the first collumn in my list with activities.